# How I install wxWidgets in msys2 correctly?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, msys2

I'm having trouble installing wxWidgets in msys2, I used pacman to install the library

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-wxwidgets3.0-msw
```

But when I try to execute a test file it gives me this error

> fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory

Reading online I see that are in another methods of installing the library you have to compile it, but I can't find any information in regards to installing it with pacman.

I also tried to compile it myself with Cmake following the instructions in the wxwidgets page but I failed and I want to see what should I do now.

What I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Your `pacman -S mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-wxwidgets3.0-msw` looks correct if you are using `clang` as your compiler and not `g++`

Comment: For MinGW there are other packages: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-wxwidgets3.0-msw?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-wxwidgets3.0-msw?repo=mingw64)

Comment: @higo_in_trouble, how did you try to build the sample? Can you give us the exact command?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never... I'm trying to go through this myself. I remembered from doing it in the dim and distant past, that there is a program called 'wx-config' that ships with the wxwidgets distribution. If you run it with various flags, it will tell you what compiler arguments you need to get the thing to build and link. For a non-trivial program, you'll probably want to use a build system. I'm a dinosaur, so I use make and a makefile. If I run

```
wx-config --cxxflags
```

I get the output

```
-IC:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-3.0 -IC:/msys64/ucrt64/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMSW__ -fpermissive
```

And if I run

```
wx-config --libs
```

I get

```
-LC:/msys64/ucrt64/lib   -pipe -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -lwx_mswu_xrc-3.0 -lwx_mswu_webview-3.0 -lwx_mswu_html-3.0 -lwx_mswu_qa-3.0 -lwx_mswu_adv-3.0 -lwx_mswu_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0
```

(I'm using the ucrt64 build, you'll get different output if you're using mingw64).

So in my Makefile, I've created the following variables (amongst other):

```
WX_CPPFLAGS = -IC:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-3.0 -IC:/msys64/ucrt64/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMSW__
WX_CXXFLAGS = -fpermissive
WX_CFLAGS = -fpermissive
WX_LDLIBS = -LC:/msys64/ucrt64/lib   -pipe -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -lwx_mswu_xrc-3.0 -lwx_mswu_webview-3.0 -lwx_mswu_html-3.0 -lwx_mswu_qa-3.0 -lwx_mswu_adv-3.0 -lwx_mswu_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0

CPPFLAGS += $(WX_CPPFLAGS)
CFLAGS += $(WX_CFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += $(WX_CXXFLAGS)
LDLIBS += $(WX_LDLIBS)
```

If I then run make (mingw32-make, to build a windows executable) I can build a wxwidgets example, such as this: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html
Hope that helps someone...

Comment: You can also run `$(shell wx-config --cflags)` (and so on) in the makefile, to avoid hardcoding the flags. Also, why the heck did they add ` -fpermissive`. :c